# Is it ok to ask "is this a sentence" questions?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions

I've never studied grammar.

I want to know if something is a sentence, but don't know enough grammar to describe it and so ask a general question. Only, I think, create analogous sentences (I think?).

Is that OK?

Comment: i could go about trying to find the necessary terminology to ask the question, but it may end up a CF

Comment: i'm just gonna ask that in 3... 2...

Comment: [Related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6678/are-these-sentences-correct-is-a-title-like-this-enough-reason-to-close-a-que).

Answer (score 7):

I you're having trouble learning English, then please look up the English Learner's Stack Exchange Site, https://ell.stackexchange.com/.

If you want to know if your question is on topic, you need to be more specific in your question here. Strictly speaking asking if a particular collection of words is a sentence is off topic.

So if your question is "Is "A green baby" a sentence?", then that is off topic, as the definition of a sentence is something easily looked up.

But if your question leaves some kind of ambiguity in the definition of a collection of words as to whether they form a sentence then it's probably on topic.

It might also be worth your time looking up https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/, as they might have a similar type of question.